# Is there a way to verify if a file is a special block file in Java?

Tags: java, linux, file-attributes

I have a special use case where I need to verify if a file is a special block file (only if my java program is run on Linux). My code can already detect if it's ran on Windows or Linux, so if it's windows I simply invalidate the verification.

For Linux, I was reading about the different [FileAttributeView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html) interfaces; and the first thing that popped up was to use the [PosixFileAttributeView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/PosixFileAttributeView.html) (since block and char device files are Linux-specific), but after looking further into its Javadoc, it only gives access to the different RWX (read, write, execute permissions relative to the owner, group and others) but nothing about special block files or other file attributes. On the other hand, the [BasicFileAttributeView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributeView.html) is supported by all filesystems and has an instance method called `isOther()`, this could work but there has to be some other way that's more specific than just knowing that a file is not a regular file, directory or symlink. Knowing that it's `something other` is just too vague.. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, this is actually harder than I imagined!

To ground this in Linux, what you're looking for is the `st_mode` field from `stat()` system call (in C-world). Its different values indicate whether the file is a character device, block device, directory, etc... The first character on each line of the return from `ls -la` represent that field: `b` for block device, `d` for directory, `-` for regular file, and on. For example, if you run `ls -la /dev/sda` you'll probably get something like `brw-rw---- 1...`, because `sda` is a block device. The first line of `ls -la /opt` will be `dr-xr-xrx...` since `opt` is a directory.

(https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat, for reference)

Poking around the Javadocs, I didn't find a file class that allows direct access to this `st_mode` field. Like you mentioned, there are methods to determine if the file is a directory, file, or other, but this is not sufficient to distinguish between all the options and figure out if it's a block device.

I did find this [project](https://github.com/jnr/jnr-posix) which looks like it lets you get at that `stat()` struct in Java. It is a fair bit of overhead. Perhaps you could extract the bits you need for this application, but it might not be trivial.
The specific method you'd need to call is [`isBlockDev()`](https://github.com/jnr/jnr-posix/blob/4a3fc5e4c10846105ba4e299091d3734accb929a/src/main/java/jnr/posix/BaseFileStat.java#L80)

Hope that helps a little bit, curious to see if you figure something out, or if there's a better answer out there!

Comment: Yeah I've struggled my fair share before i decided to post a question about it >.<, the problem is that if i'm using an extra project/dependency, i could simply just do some kind of `Runtime.exec("ls")` or other and just parse the output myself ? But as you've mentioned, since it's platform dependent I guess there doesn't seem to be a native way of doing that in java..

Comment: A cleaner solution could be to just write the C code that does the system call and use JNI to retrieve an equivalent java statx structure ? But seems like too much work for checking a single attribute

Comment: I upvoted your post but i'm not sure if i should mark it as the actual answer ? You did actually give me a valid solution using the library you proposed =o I was just hoping i'd be able to find a solution that might be more manual [and with less dependencies maybe] (like reading the first magic bytes of a file to determine it's type)  but i'm not sure about if it's possible with block and char devices.